# Ramat Bet Shemesh Daled and Purim

Tags: purim

There have been many arguments over the past years regarding which day those in Bet Shemesh and specifically Ramat Bet Shemesh Daled, which is near [Yarmut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tel_Yarmuth), should keep, since Yarmut is mentioned to have had a wall at the time of Yehoshua bin Nun. They have found sections of the wall. For further details on the argument you can find it here: https://blogs.timesofisrael.com/a-case-for-shushan-purim-in-beit-shemesh/ ; https://www.ou.org/holidays/the-case-for-observing-purim-on-both-the-14th-and-15th-of-adar-in-beit-shemesh-and-ramat-beit-shemesh/ as well as p'sakim from Reb Moshe Bransdorfer and others. Although, this opinion is still in the minority.

The Chazon Ish and Rav Kook, among others, avoided using scientific discoveries to determine Halacha (for example, Professor Felix proved that Shiboles Shoeal is not oats but Reb Shlomo Zalaman Auerbach rejected this, I don't know any opinion that would determine oats as Chometz based on Professor Felix). As we see from the Chazon Ish here:    https://traditiononline.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Hazon-Ish-On-1.pdf and the conclusion of this: [https://faculty.biu.ac.il/~fixeled/FixlerFrankBliea.pdf](https://faculty.biu.ac.il/%7Efixeled/FixlerFrankBliea.pdf) that according to many, scientific evidence, does not change Halacha.

The Rabbonim who rule one should keep both days of Purim is  this based entirely on archaeology?  is this a ספק דרבנן at most?   According to some one should keep לחומרה. But surely the entirety of their evidence can’t be based on archaeology!
My question: Is there any other proof besides archaeology that this place should keep 2 days of Purim?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145495/discussion-on-question-by-fulltimekollelguy-ramat-bet-shemesh-daled-and-purim); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.